# Wordpress: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So, I'm following the example in the following codex page, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user, to determine whether a user is logged in or not, from within my plugin, and am getting the above mentioned error message:

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
```

What am I missing here?

Additional: What I was hoping to achieve, was to allow the jQuery in my code to function whether a user is logged in or not. But still, if a user is logged out, JQuery does not work:

```html
function getregions_scripts() {
    global $post;
    $tempHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    if ( in_array( $post->post_name, array( 'homepage', 'home-tests') ) && in_array( $tempHost, array( '192.0.0.0', '192.0.0.1' ) )  ){
      wp_enqueue_script(
      'getregions-script',
      plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getregions.js",
      array('jquery'),
      '1.0',
      true
    );
  }

  wp_localize_script(
    'getregions-script', // this needs to match the name of our enqueued script
    'gymRegions',      // the name of the object
    array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) // the property/value
  );
}

add_action('init','checkUserExists');
function checkUserExists(){
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getregions_scripts' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
  } else {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getregions_scripts' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries', 'showcountries_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_no_priv_showcountries_frontend', 'showcountries_frontend' );
  }
}

function showcountries_callback() {
}
```

Comment: Your code tell us nothing. When does the function execute, to which hook is it hooked. Your code is definitely running way too early, before core functions like the one above is defined

Comment: @theog did you include wp-blog-header.php file ?

Comment: @PieterGoosen You are correct. I have added additional code above, so as to give a better indication as to what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: You have an answer already, but it's actually better to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your code inside an `init` hook, because the file that contains that function is included later on by wordpress.

```
add_action('init','your_function');
function your_function(){
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code gets rid of the error message. Many thanks. But what I was hoping to achieve as documented above, still does not work.

Comment: Solved my problem